# SBT: How to depend on a cross compiled module in the same project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two *sbt-modules* in my project:

- *comps* is cross-compiled to *Scala* 2.12 and 2.13.
- *core* is not (uses *Scala* 2.13) and depends on *comps*.

When I compile in the sbt console, I get the following error:

```
    [error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/.../"), "core"):
    [error]    myorg:myproj-comps _2.13, _2.12
```

Here is my *build.sbt*:

```
lazy val comps = project.in(file("./comps"))
  .settings(...)

lazy val core = project.in(file("./core"))
  .settings(...)
  .dependsOn(comps)
```

How can *core* depends on *comps* to take *Scala* 2.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works again. All I did was:

```
clean
```

On the `sbt-console`.